# Drag & Drop of hidden QStandardItemModel columns in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

Within a QTreeView, I would like to copy rows around by drag and drop. The corresponding Drag & drop settings look like:

```
this->setDragDropMode( QAbstractItemView::DragDrop );
this->setDropIndicatorShown( true );
```

This works fine unsing for the columns of the underlying QStandardItemModel which are visualised by the QTreeView. But not all columns of the model are visualised (see [Hide future columns of QStandardItemModel in QTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053125/hide-future-columns-of-qstandarditemmodel-in-qtreeview)):

```
    void MyViewClass::columnCountChanged(int p_nOldCount , int p_nNewCount )
    {
    QTreeView::columnCountChanged( p_nOldCount, p_nNewCount );

    for ( int i = MyViewClass::m_nColumnType; i < p_nNewCount; ++i )
    {
        setColumnHidden( i, true );
    }
}
```

**How can I copy the whole row of a QStandardItemModel by drag and drop in the QTreeView when not all columns are visualised by the QTreeView?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

One has to inherit / implement the QAbstractModel functions:

- virtual QMimeData * mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const;
- virtual bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData *p_grData, Qt::DropAction p_grAction, int p_nRow, int p_nColumn, const QModelIndex &p_grParentIdx);
- virtual QStringList mimeTypes() const;

while mimeData needs to encode the data and dropMimeData needs to decode the data and needs to insert a new row / column with the draged data.